# Convert php output to JSON

Tags: php, json

I have the following output from a PHP script:

```
one@gmail.com test1
two@gmail.com test2
```

which is generated from the following:

```
$i = 0;
  $header = array();
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);
   if (trim($buffer)!=''){
      $obj = json_decode($buffer);

       echo $obj[0]." ".$obj[2]."<br>";

      $i++;
    }
  }
fclose($handle);
```

How can i convert the output of the script into a JSON format of :

```
{"emails":[{"email":"one@gmail.com","option":test1"},{"email":"two@gmail.com","option":test2"}]}
```

The script was taken from the Mailchimp API which list the subscribers of a list.
Here is the script for reference:

```
<?php
$apikey = '1234-us7';
$list_id = '1234';
$chunk_size = 4096; //in bytes
$url = 'http://us7.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list?apikey='.$apikey.'&id='.$list_id.'&output=json';


/** a more robust client can be built using fsockopen **/
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if (!$handle) {
  echo "failed to access url\n";
} else {
  $i = 0;
  $header = array();
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);
   if (trim($buffer)!=''){
      $obj = json_decode($buffer);
      if ($i==0){
        //store the header row
        $header = $obj;
      } else {
        //echo, write to a file, queue a job, etc.
       echo $obj[0]." ".$obj[2]."<br>";


       }
      $i++;
    }
  }

  fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you just trying to pass through the mailchimp API response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$result = array();  //create a new array
  $header = array();
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);
   if (trim($buffer)!=''){
      $obj = json_decode($buffer);

       //echo $obj[0]." ".$obj[2]."<br>";  //comment out this line
       $result[] = array('email' => $obj[0], 'option' => $obj[2]);  //push new obj to the array

      $i++;
    }
  }
fclose($handle);
echo json_encode(array('emails' => $result)); // convert to json format
```

Comment: Yeap,this did the job in a second! Thank you! I'll accept when i can.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to already be in JSON, because you are using `json_decode` to get that output. So just... stop using `json_decode` on it.

Answer (score 1):

As @jessica has already mentioned, it appears that $buffer is coming to you as JSON, because you are running `json_decode(&buffer)` on it.

However, if you want to do some manipulations, arrange the data so you build an array like this:

```
$myArray = array(
    'emails' => array(
         array('email' => 'one@gmail.com','option' => 'test1'),
         array('email' => 'two@gmail.com','option' => 'test2'),
    )
);
```

Then:

```
echo json_encode(myArray);
```

Using your supllied code, it would be something like this (untested):

```
$myArray = array();
$i = 0;
$header = array();
while (!feof($handle)) {

    $buffer = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);

    if (trim($buffer)!='') {

        $obj = json_decode($buffer);

        $myArray['emails'][] = array('email' => $obj[0],'option' => $obj[2]);

        $i++;
    }
}

fclose($handle);

echo json_encode($myArray);
```